# ios open camera image from roll

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I´m creating an app that access to the Camera roll using ImagePickerController. The app has a buttom and when I tap on it the app should go to the last image saved on the roll. Using that code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
```

the app open the thumbnails and I would like to open a specific image (full screen)

Is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image will open in full view only if you want to make edit to it.

Add this line to open in full view before presenting .

```
[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
```

If you wish more function than you have two option.

1. Use your own custom control.
2. Add overlay view on `UIImagePickerController`

Refer this example to create your controls:

- [DLCImagePickerController](https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController)
- [AGImagePickerController](https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController)

Comment: hi CRDave, I added the code and when I tap on the button, the library is showed and when I tap on an specific image, the image is opened with a toolbar (Cancel and Use). I would like to open only the image with the share button, delete button , etc. The same behavior of the iphone roll

Comment: Than you have to create your own view. his is not possible with UIImagePickerController. Second option is you can add overlay view in UIImagePickerController but it has limited function